# Unable to use Beanshell Pre processor varible in another request

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Unable to use the Bean Shell Pre-Processor variable in the HTTP sampler or in another HTTP request.

```
Thread Group

Random variable - Id

HTTP sampler (XML body - <id> ${var1}</id>)

   BeanShell Pre Processor


     vars.put("RANDOM_NUMBER", "T${Id}E${Id}");

     var var1 = vars.get("RANDOM_NUMBER");

     log.info("var1 value is " + var1);

HTTP Request (https://${var1})
```

In the logs, can print the value var1 value is T20E33.

However when trying to refer the variable in the same HTTP sampler or in another HTTP request, the value is not replaced.

Referred [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924947/jmeter-using-variables-from-other-beanshell-pre-post-processors)

Even tried directly using RANDOM_NUMBER as ${RANDOM_NUMBER} in request, in this case also the value is not replaced. It goes as ${RANDOM_NUMBER}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vars.get` instead of `${}` and concatenate values

```
vars.put("RANDOM_NUMBER", "T" + vars.get("Id") + "E" + vars.get("Id"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However when tried like this, getting below issue in log.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Able to successfully get the value now. Accepted the answer.